# Android App dosnt open after restartinhg (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to after the phone is restarted, the app open automatically using this code

```
public class BroadCastReciverBoot extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static  String SMS_RECEIVED2 = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED2)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "dsjdksda", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(context, Permissions.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Also my manifest..

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Settings"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Tutorial" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Permissions">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".myBackgroundProcess" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".SmsBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".BroadCastReciverBoot"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The problem is, even after restarting the phone the application dosnt open.
I tried several things but still. Please I would appreciate any helping.

Thank You!

Comment: In order to use BOOT_COMPLETED to trigger the activity, you need to start the app at least once, and different brands may have different optimization strategies and could cause the app unable to start

Comment: Hello PatrickKen, I dont understand. I already started the app once, the I restarted my device but nothing? What should I do

Comment: Try to add `<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />` and add some logs to `onReceive()` to check.

Comment: I already tried to add <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"

Comment: As shown in the code, even I tried adding default rather than QUICK BOOT but still nothing works...

Comment: Even I tried with emulator, it work some times and some time not. But using debugging (using real device) its dosnt work at all!